# Не корректно работает scroll в recyclerView

Tags: android

Доброго времени суток. Имеется некий recyclerView.
При пролистывании пользователем определенного элемента(Допустим 10-го) скролл автоматически пролистывается обратно до 4 элемента.
Скинуть исходники не могу, т.к кода очень много и не знаю где искать косяк.
Спрашиваю может кто сталкивался с этим и знает в чем дело.
Очень прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: без исходников это будет гадание с помощью хрустального шара

Comment: понимаю, там реально много исходников, тысячи строк кода.

Comment: тысячи строк в адаптере и инициализации recyclerView?

Comment: В layoutManager 700+ строк кода, в адаптере 200+

Comment: Проблема решена, пришлось внимательно изучить каждую строчку кода.